# Dataset observation won't convert to float

Tags: python, converters

I am trying to run a Multiple Linear Regression/Lasso/Ridge regression on Python and to do that I have to split my data into train and test. However, when I try to do this I get the following error message "ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Azerbaijan'". My dataset contains GDP growth values for each country. The GDP growth value for this country does not seem to be different than the others, so I do not understand the reason behind the error. EF1 being the name of my dataset, my code is as follows:

````
X = EF1.iloc[:, :-1] 
  
#output 
Y = EF1.iloc[:, -1] 

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split( 
    EF1.iloc[:, :-1], EF1.iloc[:, -1],  
    test_size = 0.25) 
  
print("Train data shape of X = % s and Y = % s : "%( 
    x_train.shape, y_train.shape)) 
  
print("Test data shape of X = % s and Y = % s : "%( 
    x_test.shape, y_test.shape)) 

# Apply multiple Linear Regression Model 
lreg = LinearRegression() 
lreg.fit(x_train, y_train) 

# Generate Prediction on test set 
lreg_y_pred = lreg.predict(x_test) 
  
# calculating Mean Squared Error (mse) 
mean_squared_error = np.mean((lreg_y_pred - y_test)**2) 
print("Mean squared Error on test set : ", mean_squared_error) 
  
# Putting together the coefficient and their corrsponding variable names  
lreg_coefficient = pd.DataFrame() 
lreg_coefficient["Columns"] = x_train.columns 
lreg_coefficient['Coefficient Estimate'] = pd.Series(lreg.coef_) 
print(lreg_coefficient) ```
````

Comment: It would help if you also posted a few samples from your dataset (including the offending row) and the traceback.

Comment: My dataset looks like the following:
 
Country | Business Freedom | Labor Freedom| .... | GDP Growth
Albania  | 69.3                        |        52.7          | .... |     3.9

EDIT: The error code keeps changing the name of the country, now it's giving me an error for Macedonia instead of Azerbaijan

Comment: If I understand your description of the dataset, one of the features you want to look at (according to your code, as EF1.iloc[:, :-1] takes all the columns but the last) is the country name. LinearRegression don't know how to work with strings like that. You should encode the countries with something like one hot encoding.

Comment: Also, for this problem using the country as a feature for the model doesn't sound right. It isn't relevant for the test set at all, and it might make your model try and memorize the GDP for each country it sees. I would do `EF1.iloc[:, 1:-1]` in the split line and ignore this feature completely.

Comment: Removing the country column from the analysis solved the problem! Thank you for your help!